# I want to add a user/login to role in another database without switching databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, role

I have a role / login in a 'new' database `mynewdb` with a role `"emailsender"`. I have scripted a profile for `sp_send_dbmail` and am now trying to script adding the the login to the `DatabaseMailUserRole` in `msdb` and seem to be going around in circles. Importantly I want to run my update script in `mynewdb`. I know I can use `SSMS` to do this. The question is:

How to script adding the user to the role in `T-SQL` from the `mynewdb` database without switching to `msdb`?

Answer (score 8):

```
EXEC msdb.sys.sp_executesql N'ALTER ROLE ...';
```